# How to get all the listing products in the last ten days through Amazon sp-api?

Tags: amazon-mws, amazon-selling-partner-api

I used this api:/reports/2021-06-30/reports to createReport with GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_ALL_DATA.
but the request param dataStartTime don't work. the api return all the products to me，not last ten days

as the title.How to get all the listing products in the last ten days through Amazon sp-api?